# How can I open an R Markdown file from GitHub in Google Colab?

Tags: r, r-markdown, google-colaboratory

I´d like to **create links for R markdown files** (`.Rmd`) **in a GitHub repo so that these directly open in Google Colab**.

I can do this with Python Jupyter notebooks. However, I haven't found any way to achieve the same with R Markdown files.

How can I do this?

Thanks for any help or pointer in the right direction.

PS: One of the few hints I found online mentions this link format, **which unfortunately doesn't work**:

```
https://colab.research.google.com/github/<GITHUB ACCOUNT NAME>/<REPO NAME>/blob/master/example.Rmd
```

Colab yields this error message:

```
Notebook loading error
The file has been corrupted or is not a valid notebook file.
```

However, the notebooks that I tested work properly on any other platform, e.g. RStudio etc.

Comment: I wonder if the shortcut used [here](https://twitter.com/DynamicWebPaige/status/1612837020531044352) might help you. Or at least it may help you switch to R and then see what the link should be?

Comment: @Wayne Thanks very much for the link. I already had found something similar [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-r-in-google-colab-b6e02d736497). That only makes it possible to create an R notebook in Colab from scratch. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work to open existing notebooks. But nonetheless thanks for your help!